# How to know the number of voters where the number of candidates is larger than the number of slots

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic

Our country recently held its election and I became interested in finding the number of voters who voted for a given position. Solving this problem for one slot positions (mayor, governor, etc.) is very trivial. Obviously, we just need to sum up the votes for each candidates to get the total number of voters.

```
number of voters = candidate 1 votes + candidate 2 votes + ... + candidate n votes
```

However, getting the number of voters for positions having many slots seems not to be equally easy. For example, the senatorial position has 12 slots with 33 candidates. What I want to achieve is to know the number of voters based on the current votes on those 33 candidates.

Is there an algorithm or method to solve this problem? Note that it's perfectly okay to only have the range of the possible number of voters, or any other approximations of it.

**ADDITIONAL 1**: We'll assume that each voter has voted exactly 12 candidates (for senators, for example) (no more, no less). (thanks @slebetman)

Comment: You mean each person *must* cast 12 votes or each person may cast *up to* 12 votes?

Comment: this look more like a permutation combination problem rather than an algorithmic one.

Comment: also can a person vote more than 12 times?

Comment: @thunderbird Please see **ADDTIONAL 1**.

Comment: @hammar Hmmm... It seems correct but could you please elaborate? Perhaps post an answer?

Comment: What's wrong with picking top 12 candidates based on votes gathered?

Comment: @SparKotॐ What I want to know is the *number of voters* based on the current votes.

Comment: @MarkGarcia I'm with *hammar* in that case. Interesting is when a voter casts between [1..12] votes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The requirement that each voter has voted exactly 12 times makes this easy.

1. Sum up the votes for all the candidates. This gives you the total number of votes cast in the election.
2. Divide the total number of votes by 12 to get the number of voters.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT

- Assuming that if a voter casts a vote, he casts only one vote. Then simple sum is the **maximum** number of voters.
- Assuming that a voter has max 12 votes to cast, and every voter casts 12 votes, then summing the total votes and dividing it by 12 gives the **minimum** number of voters. (As Hammar said in his answer.)

This gives you a possible range for number of voters.

Earlier, I thought there were multiple positions, and I answered with that question in mind. That is, I thought there were 12 different positions in a senatorial committee.

---

OLD

For all the positions, calculate the total number of voters (Just adding the votes for each candidate for this position will give this number, as you mentioned in the question).

By using simple set theory:

- The maximum of all these voters is your **minimum** number of voters.
- The sum of all these voters is your **maximum** number of voters, limited by the eligible voters.

This would be a very wide range, and getting an approximate number may not be feasible without any other constraints/information.